# HTTPS Proxy не работает

Tags: c#, .net, https

У меня есть свой прокси-сервер, HTTPS не работает. Туннелирование я сделал (через CONNECT и возврат браузеру HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established), оно работает. Подключаюсь к адресу (адрес мне браузер направил), все отлично. Дальше начинаются проблемы! Через NetworkStream  передаю  серверу то, что мне отправил браузер. Потом читаю, что отправил сервер. Передаю браузеру. В итоге браузер пишет, что не получил данных. Привожу свой код https обработчика (пардон, грязный):

```
static NetworkStream sns;
    static void HTTPSWorker(TcpClient s)
    {

            NetworkStream ns = s.GetStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            ns.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            string req = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
            string[] data = req.Split(' ');
            string[] ipp = data[1].Split(':');
        if (data[0] == "CONNECT")
        {

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ipp[0], int.Parse(ipp[1]));
            sns = client.GetStream();
            // sslStream = new SslStream(sns, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCert), null);
            // sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(ipp[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(ipp[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(ipp[1]);

            string strSSLResponse = "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n";
            byte[] bytSSLResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strSSLResponse);
            ns.Write(bytSSLResponse, 0, bytSSLResponse.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            ns.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            sns.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("REDIRECTED");
        }

        try
        {
            sns.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
                ns.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");

    }
```

Comment: Вы должны читать/писать данные в обеих направлениях. То есть, браузер может что-то записать в стрим, вы должны это передать конечному узлу, конечный узел может что-то записать в стрим, вы должны это передать браузеру. При том нельзя делать так просто, как вы это делаете. Например, конечный узел может делать запись несколько раз подряд, а браузер при этом ничем не ответит.

Comment: @Zergatul я просто не могу понять, каким образом это реализовать... Туннелирование уже есть, то есть уже недалеко до результата. Читаю браузер, отправляю на сервер, принимаю ответ, отправляю браузеру. Вроде все правильно, похоже на то, что вы написали, но не работает.